# Display large image in browser with original height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a situation where I want to display an image in browser with 2200px width and 1600px height in HTML. But the problem is that the image is displaying by zooming in and one zoom option is displaying in default. I want to display this image in its original size without zoom in, possibly with scrollbars. Are there any JS or jQuery plugins to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean you are viewing an image on its own in a browser rather than in a webpage? i.e. http://domain.com/image.jpg - if thats the case then you have no control over the image anymore, so you can't apply any JS/CSS rules to it

Comment: am opening a new window using window.open(imageUrl).Can you suggest me some other methods to view the image in its original size.

Comment: If you created a simple webpage that just displayed the image, such as <html><head></head><body><img src="image.jpg" width="2200px" height="1600px"></body> Then you would have control over how the image is displayed.

Comment: am using jquery for it as below.now the new window is opening but image is not loading .                                            var w = window.open();

 $(w.document.body).html("<div style='overflow:auto;'><img src='" +imageUrl + "' /></div>");

Comment: Can you upload what you have? Sounds complicated to me

Comment: I got it thanks.i have used var w = window.open();  w.document.writeln(html)